# Jersey web client with JSP

Tags: rest, jsp, web-applications, jersey, client

I am trying to get started with REST web development with java.

I've found a lot of tutorials where people write up sample RESTful web service and clients for them in Jersey. I do understand how they work and I am happy with my progress.

However, there are a couple of things that should be obvious (?) but are not so clear to me. All of the tutorials that I have gone through develop clients whose input and output is all done through the console. Is it possible to develop a client whose input and output is done through a web browser?

I've also had a quick look over JSP, which I understand is used to create dynamic web content. Is it feasible to create a Jersey client that uses JSP to get its input and print its output? I would be very grateful for any examples / sample code that demonstrate how this can be done, if this is something that can be done.

Thanks!

Comment: With webapps, you will generally consume your APIs with Javascript code (AJAX).  You can put Javascript code in your JSPs or plain HTML pages.